# Need help about recursive definition for two languages S* and T* where S={aa,b} and T={w1,w2,w3,w4}

Tags: recursion, definitions, automata-theory, kleene-star

I am currently taking a course of Theory of Automata and i came up with following problems. I came up with the answer of 1st one but confused about the statement of 2nd question.

**(i) Give a recursive definition for the language S* where S = {aa,b}.**

> Step 1:
>   Lamba, aa, b are in S.
>
> Step 2:
>   If x is in S then so is bx and xb.

I want to confirm my confirm my answer.

And the following the question i am totally confused about and isn't able to come up with an answer.

**(ii) Give a recursive definition for the language T* where
T = {w1, w2, w3, w4}
where these w's are some particular words.**

Answer (score 0):

(i) Very close. You are missing at least one rule, and you have one rule which is not needed. You need either `xaa` or `aax` in step 2. You need only one of the rules you give in step 2, not both. Otherwise this is right. A minimal recursive definition is:

1. lambda is in S
2. if x is in S, then aax and bx are in S.

(ii) Same as (i), just generalized. Answer is

1. lambda is in T
2. if x is in T, then w1x, w2x, w3x, w4x are in T.